# Programmatically create an online refund in Magento 1.6.0.0

Tags: magento-1.6, creditmemo, refund

I'm trying to create an online refund of a certain amount (e.g. 10 EUR = is lower than refundable amount). The refund is independent of order items. I can refund online in admin panel but everytime I do it programmatically it will do an offline refund. Please help! I must have overlooked something.

```
# $order and $invoice are given here
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);
$data = array();
$data['shipping_amount'] = 0;
$data['grand_total'] = 0;
$data['base_grand_total'] = 0;
$data['adjustment_positive'] = 10;
$data['qtys'] = array(0 => 0);
$creditmemo = $service->prepareInvoiceCreditmemo($invoice, $data);
$creditmemo->setShippingAmount(0);
$creditmemo->setGrandTotal($data['adjustment_positive']);
$creditmemo->setRefundRequested(true);
$creditmemo->setOfflineRequested(false);
$creditmemo->setPaymentRefundDisallowed(false);
if(Mage::registry('current_creditmemo')) {
    Mage::unregister('current_creditmemo');
}
Mage::register('current_creditmemo', $creditmemo);
$creditmemo->refund();
# here follows the transactionSave: $this->_saveCreditmemo($creditmemo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it! I just had to replace the last line $creditmemo->refund(); with:

```
$creditmemo->register();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

**1.** `@param string $orderIncrementId`

**2.**

```
 @param array $creditmemoData array('qtys' => array('sku1' => qty1, ... , 'skuN' => qtyN),
          'shipping_amount' => value, 'adjustment_positive' => value, 'adjustment_negative' => value)
```

**3.**  `@param string|null $comment`

**4.** `@param bool $includeComment`

**5.** `@param string $refundToStoreCreditAmount`

**6**  `@return string $creditmemoIncrementId`

```
$orderIncrementId ='200000010'; 


$creditmemoData = array(
'qtys' => array(
'order_item_id' => 3,
'qty' => '1'),
'shipping_amount' => null,
'adjustment_positive' => '0',
'adjustment_negative' => null);


 $comment= 'comment for credit memo';

$notifyCustomer =  true;
 $includeComment = false;
$refundToStoreCreditAmount= '1';

 $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIncrementId, 'increment_id');

       if ($order->getId() && $order->canCreditmemo()) {

             /** @var $service Mage_Sales_Model_Service_Order */
        $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order);





        $data = isset($data) ? $data : array();

        if (isset($data['qtys']) && count($data['qtys'])) {
            $qtysArray = array();
            foreach ($data['qtys'] as $qKey => $qVal) {
                // Save backward compatibility
                if (is_array($qVal)) {
                    if (isset($qVal['order_item_id']) && isset($qVal['qty'])) {
                        $qtysArray[$qVal['order_item_id']] = $qVal['qty'];
                    }
                } else {
                    $qtysArray[$qKey] = $qVal;
                }
            }
            $data['qtys'] = $qtysArray;
        }


        /** @var $creditmemo Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo */
        $creditmemo = $service->prepareCreditmemo($creditmemoData);
                // refund to Store Credit
        if ($refundToStoreCreditAmount) {
            // check if refund to Store Credit is available
            if ($order->getCustomerIsGuest()) {
               // 'cannot_refund_to_storecredit';
            }
            $refundToStoreCreditAmount = max(
                0,
                min($creditmemo->getBaseCustomerBalanceReturnMax(), $refundToStoreCreditAmount)
            );
            if ($refundToStoreCreditAmount) {
                $refundToStoreCreditAmount = $creditmemo->getStore()->roundPrice($refundToStoreCreditAmount);
                $creditmemo->setBaseCustomerBalanceTotalRefunded($refundToStoreCreditAmount);
                $refundToStoreCreditAmount = $creditmemo->getStore()->roundPrice(
                    $refundToStoreCreditAmount*$order->getStoreToOrderRate()
                );
                // this field can be used by customer balance observer
                $creditmemo->setBsCustomerBalTotalRefunded($refundToStoreCreditAmount);
                // setting flag to make actual refund to customer balance after credit memo save
                $creditmemo->setCustomerBalanceRefundFlag(true);
            }
        }
        $creditmemo->setPaymentRefundDisallowed(true)->register();
        // add comment to creditmemo
 // add comment to creditmemo
        if (!empty($comment)) {
            $creditmemo->addComment($comment, $notifyCustomer);
        }
                   Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                ->addObject($creditmemo)
                ->addObject($order)
                ->save();
            // send email notification
            $creditmemo->sendEmail($notifyCustomer, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));

        }
```

Comment: Hi @Amit Can we have this for Magento 2?

Comment: @AnkitShah Did you get soln for Magento 2 creditmemo  with adjustment fee ...?

Comment: Can we Refund Orders to Payment Method ?